# datatable select method for datetime on date filter

Tags: vb.net

I have a datatable "dt" with a column "

> datetime"(format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM')

i need to retrieve the set of rows such that

```
dt.select("datetime='"& dateString &"'").rows
```

where "`dateString`" has a date format "`dd/MM/yyyy`"

Comment: You can `CAST` the datetime to string if using sql queries, else use linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("datetime").Substring(0, 9) = datestring).CopyToDataTable
```